# Fulfill Template Field From Code Docusign API SDK Java

Tags: java, templates, sdk, docusignapi

I have the following use-case.

I have a template. That template contains a text field and a signature field, both required.
I create an envelope from that template, but when I create the envelope, I want to pre-fill the text field with some data, and then lock it so that the debtor can't change it.
All of this has to be done via the API, not manually.
Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Comment: We don't do your work for you. Try a few things then come back if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this in this GitHub post: https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/issues/75

You will need to read a good part of the post to understand, but the key part is in this code:

```
// add code after this line
tRole.RoleName = "Applicant";

// Add the following code... 
tRole.Tabs = new Tabs();
tRole.Tabs.TextTabs = new List<Text>();
Text textTab = new Text();
textTab.TabLabel = "userinfo";
textTab.Value = "RedPlanetNote2";
tRole.Tabs.TextTabs.Add(textTab);

// make sure to do the above before you add the role to the roles list
List<TemplateRole> rolesList = new List<TemplateRole>() { tRole };
```

Hope it helps.